# utilização de mysqli_prepare previne os principais ataques de sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Eu sei que afunção mysqli_prepare é utilizada para preparar as consultas SQL e protegê-las contra SQL Injection.

Encontrei duas páginas sobre SQL Injection:

1. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
2. https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-cheat-sheet/

Estou começando a estudar sobre o assunto, e queria saber se a função mysqli_prepare consegue prevenir esses casos, ou se precisaria de "algo mais" no meu script PHP além da mysqli_prepare.

A minha dúvida é:

A utilização de mysqli_prepare previne TODOS os ataques de SQL Injection, ou é restrita aos principais tipos de ataques de SQL Injection ?

Comment: Possível duplicidade http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

O mysql_prepare evita SQLinjection, desde que, você utilize parâmetros na query.
Se você utilizar o mysql_prepare concatenado os valores dos campos com a query, não vai adiantar nada, porém, as funções mysql_* são consideradas obsoletas.
Eu indicaria você a utilizar PDO, é muito bom para trabalhar com banco de dados, e se um dia você precisar trocar seu banco de dados, será muito mais simples com PDO.

Comment: A pergunta é de mysqli_ e não mysql_. No caso PDO seria inferior ao perguntado (mysql_ sem o "i" é problema. PDO é melhor que mysql_, mas  mysql **i** _ é muito melhor que PDO para usar com MySQL pq foi feita pra isso, principalmente na parte de segurança, que não é só simulado concatenado igual PDO). A parte de usar parametro tá certinha. Sò precisa consertar a recomendação furada.

Answer (score -2):

> The purpose of prepared statements is to not include data in your SQL statements. Including them in your SQL statements is NOT safe. Always use prepared statements. They are cleaner to use (code easier to read) and not prone to SQL injections.
>
> Escaping strings to include in SQL statements doesn't work very well in some locales hence it is not safe.

Tradução:

> O propósito das declarações preparadas é não incluires dados nas instruções de SQL
>
> "Escapar strings" para se incluir em instruções SQL não funcionam em alguns casos, portanto não é seguro

Retirado de [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Apesar de sua boa itenção em ajudar, o idioma do site é português, e é esperado que tanto perguntas e respostas também seja, mesmo que sejam citações. Por isso, para não desqualificarem sua resposta com negativos, você poderia traduzir essa citação.